# Android 10 - converting documentUri to mediaStoreUri throws error

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

can anyone answer why I got a this exception while trying to get mediaUri from documentUri.
I want to query a contentResolver with the mediaUri to get all audioFiles from external storage

```
Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(mContext,docUri); 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult Result erreicht " + requestCode);

    if (requestCode != PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "no selection");
        return;
    }

    mUri = data.getData();
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(mUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(mUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(mUri));
    docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(mUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(mUri));

    Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(mContext, docUri);
}
```

`mUri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads`

`docUri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads/document/downloads`

Stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cl.languagetranslation.testandroid10, PID: 29419
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads flg=0xc3 }} to activity {com.cl.languagetranslation.testandroid10/com.cl.languagetranslation.testandroid10.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2077)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:658)
    at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:558)
    at android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(ContentProviderClient.java:546)
    at android.provider.MediaStore.getMediaUri(MediaStore.java:3501)
    at com.cl.languagetranslation.testandroid10.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:121)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4838)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Thanks for helping! 
Gettint audioFiles from storage is realy a hard job...there are others who also struggling ...so, I'm not alone trying to do this...

GGK

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide the complete stack trace, along with all of your code that is referenced in that stack trace.

Comment: You should use getMediaUri() for a file. Not for a tree as you do.

Comment: Thanks for that point. Is there a way to do that recursivle - to get all files (also from subdirectories) recursivle from `mediaStore`?

Comment: Media store will deliver default all files neglecting directories.

Comment: and how can I query all files recursively starting from an entry point (this entry point must be a directory)?

Comment: `Media store will deliver default all files`. That has been said. So there is no need for recursion. But this all has nothing to do with the subject of your post.

Comment: thanks. I will try your suggest solution and post another question how to query `mediaStore` to get all files

Answer (score 0):

getMediaUri() allows apps with Storage Access Framework permissions to convert between MediaStore and DocumentsProvider Uris that refer to the same underlying item. Note that this method doesn't grant any new permissions; callers must already hold permissions obtained with Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs.